# Change table to two-column design on small screens

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-tables

I have `<table>` and I need it to be two-column on small screens. Here is what it looks like on large screen:
[image: large screen]
<sub>(source: [firefoxusercontent.com](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/7a347038-f520-45f5-a468-4dd328ae076a.png))</sub>

And here is what it currently looks like on small screen (I screenshoted whole website, you can see about 1/3 of the page at once).

[image: small screen]
<sub>(source: [firefoxusercontent.com](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/1575ee25-e86f-4c67-91b4-f38263ac1dc1.png))</sub>

When on small screen, there's ton of unused space on the right of the table on the top. So I'd like to have the table split into two columns - via CSS if possible.

HTML of the table looks like this:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <h1 class="content-subhead">Průměry</h1>
        <table class="pure-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/student/subject/Čj">Čj</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        A
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/student/subject/SM">SM</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Z
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I use [purecss](https://purecss.io/). The weird classes of the div mean: Make this table occupy the whole grid row, except when there is big screen (no smartphone), then make this occupy 1/3 of the grid row.

Here is full [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9zy08xen/).

Comment: Your screenshots were broken

Comment: @Viira I just fixed them, thanks

Comment: But in the HTML  you have only provided a part of the code. umm.. can you fork up in a codepen or a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Viira Sure, here: https://jsfiddle.net/9zy08xen/

Comment: Yeah got it i figured out the problem

Answer (score 0):

basic HTML code is like this.

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <h1 class="content-subhead">Průměry</h1>
        <table class="pure-table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>0</th>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Po</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Ut</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>St</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>Po</td>
                 </tr> 
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and if you want to add css, then check this link https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.

It is because of the class `pure-u-1`  because this will be in 100% width when viewing it in mobile screens.

change it to `pure-u-2` so that it will split into two parts

I can't add the whole code here, so I'm updating the fiddle .

```html
<div class="pure-u-2 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <h1 class="content-subhead">Průměry</h1>
        <table class="pure-table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/student/subject/Čj">Čj</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        A
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ...
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/student/subject/SM">SM</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Z
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/9zy08xen/2/

Comment: Thank you. And how would you do something like this? ![screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/eUqKInP.png)